# MySQL is not using my certificate, uses its own self-signed

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssl

I have tried to find an answer to this and I have come up empty.

I have a certificate from LetsEncrypt that I use for all my SSL needs.  It is valid for all the DNS names that I am trying to use.  Today I tried to get it working for MySQL, but MySQL insists on using its own self-signed cert.

MySQL version is 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 from Ubuntu packages.

I have created /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/zz-ssl.conf with these contents:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/certs/local/mainchain.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/cert.pem
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

But the log says this:

```
2021-08-08T16:16:57.982003Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-08-08T16:16:57.982227Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-08-08T16:16:57.983344Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
```

I tried deleting /var/lib/mysql/*.pem ... but when I restart mysql, all those files come back with updated timestamps.  MySQL seems determined to use its own self-signed certificate and not the one I have configured.  I figure I am missing something that should be obvious but isn't.

The file /etc/mysql/cert.pem referenced in my config is owned by mysql:mysql and has 0600 permissions.  It is a copy of the certificate file I use for everything else, it contains the server cert, the private key, and the LetsEncrypt issuing cert.

Comment: I discovered one problem:  The files in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d must have a .cnf extension or they will not be used.  I had a .conf extenstion.  I renamed it, and now things are different, but still not working.  Logfile contains:

2021-08-08T16:40:09.702267Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011302] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"'

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out.  The config files must have a .cnf file extension or mysql ignores them.  And once I fixed that, I had a permission problem -- I had split the cert file into three separate files, but the other two files were owned by root:root.  Once I fixed that, everything worked.